# Using AngularJS within or alongside a CMS

Tags: angularjs, content-management-system, orchardcms

I was looking at using a CMS (Orchard CMS) to manage the front end for an upcoming web project when it was suggested that I make use of AngularJS for the "dashboard". As I am not very familiar with AngularJS I started reading about it and looking at some tutorials.

What I am wondering is if AngularJS can work within a CMS such as Orchard? I thought a CMS would be a good idea so end users can modify content as needed. AngularJS was suggested for use on our "dashboard" as it would make displaying dynamic content and updates much easier to implement.

Does a CMS framework work well alongside the AngularJS framework or are the two mutually exclusive frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, no problem. You can use Angular, or any JS framework you'd like to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this cms based on [angularJs](http://www.angularjscms.com/index.php/angularjs-cms/) pretty easy to use for making angularjs websites.

Comment: the link is broken